# Online pronunciation dictionary for conversational version of phrases

Tags: discussion, online-resources, pronunciation

Is there any online pronunciation dictionary which shows conversational version of phrases e.g.
`/ə ˈkʌpə tiː/`
instead of
`/ˈə ˈkʌp ˈəv ˈtiː/` ?

Comment: Requests for resources are off-topic. However, I always find [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/) to be helpful, and more accurate than others.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources.

Comment: Tell me please where can I ask this question?

Comment: [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/) gives audio for pronunciation.

Comment: You may also want to search on ell.srackexchange.com or Language Learners.SE which may have better resources for learners

Comment: @Mick According to https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11013/131620 requests for resources are on-topic on meta ?

Comment: I pasted your IPA into the site I use for online translation of IPA to audio - *Amazon Web Services' Polly text-to-speech service with Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML)* as recommended by https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/20821 and the first one did not sound conversational at all; it sounded hard to understand and only the second one was clear ?

Comment: Most dictionaries just do words, and when they do phrases they usually don't do transcription of the natural pronunciation of those phrases. It is usually only in language classes or linguistics texts that discuss the patterns for how one word flows properly into the next. So I suspect the real answer to your question is 'no, no such thing exists'. But to get what you're after, how to pronounce phrases well, follow real life pronunciation along with text, which you might get with closed captions on youtube, or forvo.com (@1006a)

Answer (score 2):

[Forvo.com](https://forvo.com/) is a crowd-sourced "pronouncing dictionary" that aims to have recordings of pronunciations for every word in the world. It doesn't use IPA, but if you want to know how a word is pronounced there's no substitute for actually hearing it pronounced.

Forvo's coverage for English is very good, usually with recordings in multiple dialects for more common words. It also allows you to request pronunciations of words and phrases, so if you don't see what you are looking for you can request it and English speakers will be given the chance to pronounce it.

[Searching for "tea"](https://forvo.com/search/cup%20tea/) turns up quite a few phrases, including [***cup of tea***](https://forvo.com/phrase/cup_of_tea/) itself (but lacking an article) and also longer phrases like

- [Can I have **a cup of tea**?](https://forvo.com/phrase/can_i_have_a_cup_of_tea%253F/)
- [There's nothing better that snuggling on the sofa with a blanket and **a cup of tea**](https://forvo.com/phrase/there%27s_nothing_better_that_snuggling_on_the_sofa_with_a_blanket_and_a_cup_of_tea/)
- [Would you like **a cup of tea**, or perhaps a coffee instead?](https://forvo.com/phrase/would_you_like_a_cup_of_tea%2C_or_perhaps_a_coffee_instead%253F/)

You can also see where in the world the speaker lives—the speakers of these phrases are mostly from the US and Australia (there are several UK speakers [pronouncing the word *tea*](https://forvo.com/word/tea/#en) in abstract, but somewhat to my surprise not any of the tea phrases that I looked at).

Speakers tend to enunciate a bit more than one would in ordinary, casual speech, but I think you will still get a better sense of the "conversational" pronunciations here than in most dictionaries. And, in fact, you can also get pronunciations for slang terms that often aren't covered by dictionaries; relevant to your example, you can find several pronunciations of both [*cuppa*](https://forvo.com/word/cuppa/#en) and [*nice cuppa cha*](https://forvo.com/word/nice_cuppa_cha/#en).

Comment: Thank you, but I need to see a transcription of a text so I can read it aloud. Would you be so kind as to help me to find a resource which allows to see a conversation transcription?